# Strange CA certificate prompt

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

My network went down for a minute today, then this window popped up:

[image: Certificate popup.]

Can someone here clarify this for me? I was using firefox. I had google, youtube and outlook open. My name isn't even close to Daniel, nor a nickname of it.

Comment: What site did this happen for?

Comment: Yeah, can you add some more information because the `Issued to / by` and `Validity` make this look like a very old test certificate made by some developer named Daniel, it which case your browser is right not to trust it!

Comment: @NeilSmithline

I added some more information in the main post. I was browsing reddit, outlook and youtube when my internet went out, then the prompt came up.
 
Here are some additional pictures: 
http://prntscr.com/b9aflo
http://prntscr.com/b9ag57

Comment: Ran a root certificate check. Nothing strange turned up.
Ran Avira: 68 detections. Ran it again: 0 detections.
My computer seems clean now.

Comment: Your computer isn't necessarily clean, it just means that Avira can't find anything it knows about.

Comment: Root certificate check means nothing, you mean the local store? Malware can pop stuff in and out of there at will. Use a portable version of Firefox and see if you have cert issues. It has its own certificate store and while it's not that hard to exploit it, the malware might have a more difficult time exploiting it and especially a portable version (depending on where the keystore databases are put in a portable version).

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76599)

Comment: There is 2 possibilities. i. This is a social engineering fake certificate windows, which actually pop up by browser from a malware advertisement, which try to trick you to click on any tab or install button. 
ii. One of your program open having unknown vulnerabilities and try to download something to install this cert file. 
The first case is the likely results.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your router rebooted. While booting, it redirected all web connections to it's local interface (eg. what is usually shown at 192.168.1.1). It has such invalid and expired certificate at https://192.168.1.1 During that brief period, you requested an https webpage, that was redirected to the router, which returned its cert and, as it is invalid, you got that prompt.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way I can reproduce this event?

Comment: So you think the router has a cert issued to someone named Daniel?  That seems rather unlikely to me

Comment: Well, no. But in reproducing the event, I would be able to rule out the possibilities of an attack.

Comment: The cert date is 2006. The issuer is named Daniel, probably OP's account name. If the router is probing this kind of data and spoofing CA's and in such a bad way, I'd be pretty shocked.

Comment: To try and reproduce this try to manually go to your router's web interface over HTTPS. If this answer is indeed true (it is a possibility, but to me it seems very unlikely) then the certificate prompt should appear again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The CA prompt doesn't seem reproducible.